# Retrieve recordId and sObjectName from utility bar component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

I'm trying to retrieve recordId and sObjectName from a component put on the utility bar.
The point is it always retrieves me 'undefined' in both cases.

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.get("v.sObjectName"));
    console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or it's just that I can't retrieve it from an utility bar component? And if that's so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

force:hasRecordId only works in certain contexts. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation) states:

> These unsupported contexts include a few contexts that might seem like they should have access to the current record. Examples of these other contexts include the following:
>
> - Invoking the component from a global action (even when you’re on a record page)
> - Invoking the component from header or footer navigation in a community (even if the page shows a record)

While it does not specifically call it out, I would not be surprised to note that a utility bar cannot detect this value.

Comment: In fact, the documentation does mention this: Important The recordId attribute is set only when you *place or invoke the component in an explicit record context. For example, when you place the component directly on a record page layout, or invoke it as an object-specific action from a record page or object home. In all other cases, such as when you invoke the component as a global action, or create the component programmatically inside another component, recordId isn’t set*, and your component shouldn’t depend on it.*